# Clean way of Extending Stud for Mounting on Drywall

Tags: mounting, studs, mount

I am trying to mount hooks onto my walls to hang a crossbar for a photography backdrop roll. The backdrops are 86 inches.

However below there is a shelf that slighty jets into the area where the backdrop would be once it is hanging down. It jets into that space by like a quarter of an inch. So I only have around 85.5 or 85.75 of the desired 86 inches to work with. How do I extend the stud by half an inch (so the backdrop mount wont be in the stud directly but still supported by it) without mounting a separate piece wood?

A mounting plate is ok, just looking for something small and inconspicuous. I am trying to keep it clean looking. Its only half an inch at most. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use the mounting plate as you suggest, but if it is wood have you already excluded it?

Comment: @SolarMike Im not excluding wood entirely. Maybe I'll just cut a small piece of wood and paint it white. Just cant have a beam across the two studs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the cross bar only has two mounts you only need the two mounts to come out 1/2" from where they would normally site.

I'd just cut a couple squares of 1/2" plywood and then either screw the squares to the studs and the mounts to the squares or if the weight of the cross bar with backdrop is significant then get screws that are 1/2" longer than the ones you would have normally mounted with.  The squares then just act as spacers to push the cross bar out the 1/2" front the face of the wall.

Answer (score 2):

I know that your desire is to not mount any more wood but from the description that you gave it seems like the very best choice is to actually mount a 1x4 or 1x6 board across the width of the wall and screw into the various studs. Such board could even be full room width or at least longer than the backdrop width.

If this board had the screw heads counter sunk and then filled in and then sanded, primed and painted to a color to match the wall it would be better looking that you might imagine.

This board would give you ultra flexibility where to mount the hooks that the backdrop hangs from.